# create mychannel Rejecting deliver request for because of consenter error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Error:

```
2020-10-23 09:36:01.590 UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 045 [channel: mychannel] Rejecting deliver request for ip:port because of consenter error
```

Comment: Does anyone know why?

Comment: Could you share more info about your configuration and the steps you followed?

Comment: I updated crypto-config.yml including 2 orgs and 3 orderers, and then I updated configtx.yml which can be found in https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000037603203?_ea=75383555. When I started all fabric docker containers including orderers、peers，CAs and CLIs, they are all fine, but when I try to create a channel within CLI docker container, the error above occured.

Comment: Could you try removing the docker volumes and containers and, trying the procedure again? It seems to be a problem related to the crypto material

Comment: Thank you so much. It works for me. I removed all docker volumes with "docker volume prune". But I do not know why.